# Angular performance with function expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

What are the performance implications of running a function within an Angular expression? For example:

```
<button ng-if="isValid()">Valid</button>
```

I'm assuming the function isValid() is being run for each digest loop, which occur many times per second. What options are available within Angular for improving the performance here?

One idea would be to run isValid() within a timeout function a few times a second, then setting a scope variable, so I can control the speed of the "digest". Are there other options people use?

Comment: Using function when binding is not a good idea at all, but sometimes it can be necessary. Anyways, How `isValid()` looks like? Can you show?

Comment: isValid is a function which returns true or false, and does quite a bit of work - looping through an internal structure and calling many functions.

Comment: What does the button should do on click?

Comment: Not relevant to the question. It could be a link or any DOM element for that matter.

Comment: Hmm, I think it could be, you can move the `isValid()` inside the button click and prevent the natural action in case it return false.

Comment: this doesn't even make sense. `isValid()` returns `true` or `false`, and if `false`, it won't even show, so how could it **not show**, and still evaluate as `false` a second time, to **show** a danger sign?

Comment: @Claies is correct in his point. However is difficult to propose an optmization without a clear vision of your scenario.

Comment: I've changed the question to "between one and three times for each digest loop" (from "at least 3 times"). The question is about performance of functions within expressions, not about the functionality when you click the button, etc.

Comment: Well, the functionality when you click the button, etc can be a way out of what I said in my first comment, your are running an expenssive function each digest cycle, it's not a good ideia at all, so my recomendation is, consider not doing this. However it's up to you Cheers ;{D

Comment: my response isn't about the click, it's about the way `ng-if` works.  when you use `ng-if`, the item doesn't even appear in the DOM if the expression is `false`.  Therefore, there is no reason to conditionally format the item (using this same expression), since if the item is `true`, it's visible, and therefore will use the `success` class, but if `false` it won't be in the DOM to have a class added.

Comment: I've removed all superfluous elements of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think if function body is just a simple logic comparison, won't affect performance, but if it gets complex, you can try profiling your code via chrome tools to see how much is performing,

Another alternative is also you can try binding the ng-if to a controller scope property instead and modify the value from other part of your controller's code, so maybe you can apply kind of debounce (https://github.com/shahata/angular-debounce) technique to avoid set the scope variable tons of times

Comment: I have said in comments this is a complex function. Debounce is an interesting idea, I will read up on that now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're checking if a form is valid before submitting. First of all, your `ng-if` on the button defeats the purpose of using the same function to conditionally apply a class, since it won't even be in the DOM if `isValid()` returns false.

You should be able to use `ng-pattern`, `ng-change` hooks on your inputs to determine validity as the user is entering form values. Then on your button you can apply the class based on the form's validity:

```
<button ng-class="{
       'btn-success': myFormName.$valid,
        'btn-danger':  !myFormName.$valid
    }" ng-bind="(myFormName.$valid) ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid'"></button>
```

If you want to suppress form submission, you can check validity of the form inside a function with `ng-submit` on the `<form>` tag:

```
<form name="myFormName" ng-submit="myFormName.$valid && mySubmitFunction()">
```

Comment: That's not really the point of my question. I'm asking about performance of the function and what options are available. You're getting all hung up on everything superfluous to the actual question.

Comment: I'm just trying to point out that you should be checking the validity on an input by input basis, not on every digest.

Comment: Ok, +1 inorganik, but I don't really want to assume anything about what's changing the results of isValid() (e.g. changes come from a variety of sources, like timer functions firing, watchers, etc not just form input -- which would be more straightforward case)

Comment: Curious how something that has nothing to do with user input can be invalid? If it's invalid, that means the user interacted with it. You should be checking against the specific interactions, not just running an isValid() check periodically.

Comment: For example, you can run a long running script that periodically checks the network for anything that makes isValid() change.

Comment: if you are checking something with the network - you could do the valid check in your network request callback.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to run the isValid function within an interval function, setting a simple scope variable within. For example:

```
$interval(function() {
  scope.isvalid = scope.isValid();
}, 100);
```

This will run every 100ms, but is probably preferable to the number of calls the digest makes. You can also use $watch or $observe to reduce the number of calls.